# Can i sort a Array in Swift with custom logic for sorting

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, swift2

I have been through almost all question of stackoverflow regarding it's answer where it says

```
array.sort({
    $0.name < $1.name
})
```

But I do not want this at all...

I have Array containing custom objects and I want to sort it as per it's one of the variable name status ... but not is ascending or descending order ... that sorting depends on the status...

Here is the equivalent Objective C code

```
@interface NSString (StatusComparison)
- (NSComparisonResult)statusCompare:(NSString*)otherStatus;
@end
@implementation NSString (WeekdayComparison)
- (NSComparisonResult)statusCompare:(NSString*)otherDay {

NSArray *allStatus = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Immediate",@"Near",@"Far",@"Unknown",ENTER_IN_REGION,EXIT_REGION,START_MONITORING,FAIL,NOT_STARTED, nil];

    NSUInteger selfIndex = [allStatus indexOfObject:self];
    NSUInteger otherDayIndex = [allStatus indexOfObject:otherDay];

    if (selfIndex < otherDayIndex) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if (selfIndex > otherDayIndex) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
@end

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"status" ascending:YES selector:@selector(statusCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
self.dataArray = [self.dataArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

**How can I do the same thing in Swift. Please read the entire question before marking it as duplicate... It's not duplicate**

Comment: This still is a duplicate. I cannot see how this is any different, except you're using a custom ordering for sorting. What is the point that does not make this a dup?

Comment: You can not use that < > logic here ... it doesn't solve the problem ... solution of the problem is in the answers given below ... which differes from generic answer

Comment: Yes, you can. And the answer below does, too. And no, it does not differ from the generic answer 'use code to describe the order you'd like to impose'.

Comment: @JanGreve yes i got it ... but the indexOf thing was not generic and i was missing tht... which i couldn't find anywhere else

Answer (score 3):

The Swift equivalent is

```
dataArray.sortInPlace {
  return allStatus.indexOf($0.status)! < allStatus.indexOf($1.status)!
}
```

The `allStatus` array could be declared in the sort closure as well as somewhere in global scope or before the closure in local scope.

---

In Swift it might be preferable to declare the `allStatus` contents as `enum` type with `Int` raw value type and the `status` property in your custom class as the enum type. The benefit is a predictable number of cases and no potential optionals.

For example

```
enum Status : Int {
  case Immediate = 0, Near, Far, Unknown, FAIL
  var stringValue : String  { return String(self) }
}


dataArray.sortInPlace {
  return $0.status.rawValue < $1.status.rawValue
}
```

You can still get the string representation of the enum cases with

```
dataArray[0].status.stringValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example in Swift would be:

```
["Near", "Immediate", "Far"].sort { (status1, status2) in
    let statuses = ["Immediate", "Near", "Far", "Unknown"]
    guard let index1 = statuses.indexOf(status1), index2 = statuses.indexOf(status2) else {
        return false
    }

    return index1 < index2
} // Prints ["Immediate", "Near", "Far"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
array.sort({
    $0.name < $1.name 
})
```

This is just a short hand for passing closure as an argument. You can have a complete function with two arguments, which you can pass to this sort method.

Have a look at this [Swift closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)